# C# Add watermark text to word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, watermark

I cannot seem to find a simple way to insert a watermark text in a word document.

In word you have to go to design--> background --> watermerk. This is why I have tried to acces the background canvas, but without effect. Both give the error message not able to acces group:

```
//Try adding an text effect
doc.Background.CanvasItems.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, text, fontName, 144.0f, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0.0f, 0.0f);
//Try adding a shape
doc.Background.CanvasItems.AddShape(0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
```

If I use a regular text effect like this (https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/425760/inserting-text-as-water-mark-in-word-2007-using-c):

```
var logoWatermark = doc.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, text, fontName, (float)60, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0);
logoWatermark.Select();
logoWatermark.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
logoWatermark.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
logoWatermark.Fill.Solid();
logoWatermark.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray05;
logoWatermark.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
logoWatermark.RelativeVerticalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
logoWatermark.Left = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
logoWatermark.Top = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
logoWatermark.Height = 72;
logoWatermark.Width = 432;
```

It is just in front of the normal text and not really a background/watermark. Besides I should use this logoWaterMark on every page over and over again.

I have searched google/stackoverflow and could not find anything really usefull. (Without using a library like Aspose or e-IceBlue)

@Edit - 05-01-2016 - 12:56 
The link displayed as a duplicate is not a text and is displaying the watermark in de headers. I do not want a watermark in the header

Comment: is it what you want ? https://janewdaisy.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/how-to-insert-watermark-in-word-cvb-net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036130/add-watermark-image-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036130/add-watermark-image-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @haddow64 not a duplicate, I do not want a watermark in my header, just on the background and not an Image but a Text.

Comment: @Sliver2009: Watermarks are typically inserted as a textbox in the header of the section (When you use the command on the *Design* ribbon tab Word actually inserts such a textbox in the header). The solution in the linked post should work for you, you just need to insert a textbox instead of a picture.

Comment: @Silver2009: I support Dirk's remarks. Note that if you want this "on every page over and over again" then you DO want it "anchored" in the Header (or Footer) so that it repeats. But you can position it anywhere on the page you want, as long as it's formatted "behind the text". That would be, based on your code: logoWatermark.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;

Answer (score -1):

```
oWord.Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddTextEffect(
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1,
    "Leseexemplar",
    "Calibri",
    1F,
    Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0).Select();
Word.ShapeRange oShapeRange =
    oWord.Selection.ShapeRange;
oShapeRange.Name = cLeseexemplar + oSection.Index;

oShapeRange.Rotation = 315;
oShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
oShapeRange.Height = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(4.51F);
oShapeRange.Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(18.05F);
oShapeRange.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = -1;
oShapeRange.WrapFormat.Side = Word.WdWrapSideType.wdWrapBoth;
oShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapNone;
oShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
oShapeRange.RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
oShapeRange.Left = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
oShapeRange.Top = (float)Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;

oShapeRange.TextEffect.NormalizedHeight = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
oShapeRange.Line.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
oShapeRange.Fill.Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
oShapeRange.Fill.Solid();
oShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Word.WdColor.wdColorGray375;
oShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0.5F;
oWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument;
```